# Coding standard for parsing primitive types in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json, primitive-types

What is the best practice for parsing primitive type in iOS (int, float, BOOL etc.) while storing them in dataObjects for later use.

Should i parse it and store it as a NSNumber, or just store it as a primitive type property?

For example: if i'm getting 'userId' from server as **long** type. Should this be:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *userId;

self.userId = [element objectForKey:@"user_id"];
```

or:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) long userId;

self.userId = [[element objectForKey:@"user_id"] longValue];
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to store them in an NSArray or NSDictionary then obviously NSNumber, et al, is the way to go.  But for convenience for "everyday" use, the primitive type is better.  It can be especially frustrating testing, eg, a NSNumber of a BOOL and forgetting to take the `boolValue` of it.

Comment: Your title is about parsing - however, your question has nothing to do with *parsing*. If the server sends you a JSON, the *JSON parser* will actually "parse" the JSON text and create a representation. You'll most likely never bother about parsing the JSON yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, it's a good practice to have it in primitive form as long as you will not indulge them in heavy operations. It's one less burden for the compiler. Of course, it doesn't even cost a clock-cycle for the processor. But, it gets efficient as you move on to bigger number of data.

Answer (score 0):

If you doing too much mathematical operation or something use primitive data..

And, you can create your own getters and setter, like

```
-(long) getuserId
{
  return userID;
}

-(void) setuserId:(long) userId
{
   userID = userId;
}
```

But if you not doing any complex operation, better stick to non primitives. As performing operatins on objects like NSNumber are pretty easy and they come with predefined methods to perform operation on them.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want or need to do with it. 
Storing it as NSNumber adds a little overhead and a lot of convenience for things like converting to other value types and insertion in collection objects.

Answer (score 0):

Is the datatype a number? If it isn't, I wouldn't store it as one.

Consider you store a `BOOL` as an `NSNumber`: a later developer looking at your code might well think that the following code is sufficient:

```
if (_registered) {
// whatever
}
```

where `registered` is an `NSNumber` that looks like a `BOOL`.

Comment: That's a valid point. although i can implement a get method for _registered to return [_registered boolValue];

Answer (score 0):

On approach is a "double-headed" one:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSNumber* myBoolObj;
-(BOOL)myBool;

...

-(BOOL)myBool {
    return myBoolObj.boolValue;
}
```

By specifically picking a name ending in some word such as "Obj" (and using that suffix consistently for all such "hybrid" properties) you are not to apt to accidentally use `myBoolObj` where you meant `myBool`.  But you still have the advantage of being able to easily assign your value to/from NSDictionaries and NSArrays, etc.